# spring - oauth2 redirecting to unknown url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use OAuth2 in my spring application.

So here is my [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/xuXeKufs)

Now in `Giithub->Profile->Developer`, I have created an OAUth application,

the homepage url is : *http://localhost:8080/login*

And callback url is : *http://localhost:8080/datum*

So, whenever I run this application(runs at port 8080) and try to access any url child of *http://localhost:8080/* it takes me to **Login** at *http://localhost:8080/login*, now if I log in, it redirects me to a complex url and instantly to *http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/github*. After this doesn't matter how much I try, I always get redirected here.

*http://localhost:8080/datum* is a valid url.

I have added

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-secret=
```

in `application.properties`

**What is wrong here? What am I missing?**

Comment: Do you have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass in your application?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe , no i don't have one

Comment: Maybe have a look to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0UqG0iUpYk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the callback url to **`http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/github`**, and it solved the problem.

Comment: I would like to understand why. The only way I can get this callback to work is if I set up a custom redirect URL like you did. If I keep the defaults (/login/oauth2/code/google), it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but maybe try adding this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, can you take a look at [the](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M9Tn1rHv6cm93wokluoLyGjG0_6JB0yI/view?usp=sharing) video..

Comment: I also got this : `2019-11-03 16:19:14.457  WARN 11268 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [329] milliseconds.
`

Comment: I have found a solution, works without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but what does this does, can you tell me?

Comment: It allows configuration of Spring Security when using Spring Boot. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration#configuring-spring-boot-security